# Mail merge without saving c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I have use mail merge to word from instructor below. Now in last line it’s going to save the word file but I don’t want to save that I just want to open it without saving!
What should I do for it?
My mail merge instruction:
https://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/create-a-word-document-from-a-template-using-c-mail-merge/

Comment: As it stands, this question is off-topic according to Stack Overflow policy. All code concerned in a question should be *in* the question, not in an outside link. You can use the [edt] link below the question to include the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should replace

```
wordDoc.SaveAs("myfile.doc");
wordApp.Documents.Open("myFile.doc");
wordApp.Application.Quit();
```

With

```
wordApp.visible = true;
wordApp.Activate();
```

Now the word that has been merged didn’t require saving at first and it’s just like a draft.

Answer (score 1):

The code in that link has nothing to do with a mailmerge; all it's doing is showing how to create a *template* using mergefields as placeholders, then using C# code to overwrite the mergefields in a document created from the template via wordApp.Documents.Add. The article's claim "Word templates are created using MergeField’s in word" is misleading at best; Word templates usually don't contain mergefields and mergefields are usually not found in templates!

If you don't want to save the document, simply replace:

```
wordDoc.SaveAs("myfile.doc");
wordApp.Documents.Open("myFile.doc");
wordApp.Application.Quit();
```

with:

```
wordApp.Application.Quit(False);
```

If you want Word to remain open, omit wordApp.Application.Quit(False); also

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any article that I could use for standard mail merge and absolutely don’t save it and the end?

Comment: A true Word mailmerge has three output options: new document, printer, or email. None of these *requires* a document to be saved. I suggest you start with the basics: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705 . Once you have a handle on that, you can look into automating the merge, if necessary, for which you might review discussions such as: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/581e07c4-e0df-424d-b9c5-986cca3eee9b/word-mail-merge-automation

Comment: If you want Word to remain open, omit wordApp.Application.Quit(False); also.